# slickgrid: single nested json as tree view?

Tags: json, slickgrid

I have a single nested JSON object that I want to render.

```
{list: [{a:true},{b:[{b1:true,b2:true}]},{c:false}]}
```

and I know that slickgrid uses a tree view

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html

at the B row, I want it to be expandable to reveal b1, b2.

In this case the columns would be 'name' and 'value', the sub grid would have the same.

Comment: That example is not a true tree, but the appearance of a tree based on the items knowing their own depth (for indentation) and a filter (that handles collapsing).

Comment: @Edward that is correct. it doesn't get any deeper than the above.